# java.io.FileNotFoundException: .svn (Access is denied)

Tags: java, file-io, permissions

I'm looping through a directory in Java, trying to read each of the files. The directory contains some svn files in it which deny access. I could test the file name and skip svn files, but this solution won't be robust if I find other files with denied access. I tried this:

```
for(File f : dir.listFiles()){
if(f.canRead()){
    System.out.println("Trying " + f.getAbsolutePath());
    try{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    continue;
}
}
```

When I get to the .svn file, however, it doesn't skip; I get this printout:

```
Trying C:\dir\.svn
java.io.FileNotFoundException: dir\.svn (Access is denied)
```

`canRead()`,`canWrite()`, and `canExecute()` all have the same problem.
Is there something besides `canXXX()` that I can use to skip denied access files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.svn` is a directory. It's probably not something you can read with a `Scanner`.

Change your condition to this:

```
if(f.canRead() && !f.isDirectory())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can catch the `FileNotFoundException` and move to the next file.

Comment: Exactly. You have to do that anyway, why write additional code? I would just filter out directories and use try/catch.